# Rails - How to assign a value to a form through a script and reload it with the assigned value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

For my rails application, I have a form that saves "content" in my model when submitted.  How do I modify my script below and use "Sessions" so that "onSuccess(event)", I assign the contents of the alert as a temporary value to `:content` and my page reloads/refreshes with the content of the alert inside the text_area?

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.blogs.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, label: "Blog", :class => "redactor" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<script>

    ...

    function onSuccess(event) {
      alert('NICE! ' + event.data.Id + ' was added.');
    }

    ...

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are an option with ajax

```
<%= form_for [@project, @project.blogs.build], :remote => true, :html => { :id => "ajax_form" } do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, label: "Blog", :class => "redactor", :id => "change_me" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<script>

    $(function() {
      $("#ajax_form").bind('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
         $("#change_me").val("changed");
      }).bind('ajax:error', function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(status);
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but the page does not refresh with the event.data.ID value in my redactor rails form. Do you know why?

Comment: @spl, not the same thing. Perhaps what you need.

Answer (score 0):

if you use redactor.js.

```
function onSuccess(event) {
  $('.redactor').redactor('insertText', 'NICE! ' + event.data.Id + ' was added.');
}
```